# C# Custom bind in DataGridView (WinForm)

Tags: c#

I have three classes

```
public class FeatureBook
{
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public String name { get; set; }
        public String type { get; set; }
}
public class Feature
{
        public String feature_id { get; set; }
        public String value { get; set; }
}
public class Human {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public bool validated { get; set; }
        public List<Feature> features { get; set; }
        public override String ToString() => Id;
}
```

`Human` has `List<Feature>`. `Feature` is linked to `FeatureBook` by `feature_id`

And I have DataGridView.

How can I get something like in the picture:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did you stuck?

Comment: I have no idea, how do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, for such of functionality, i'd use 2 datagridviews with master-detail relationship.

Second of all, if you would like to bind data to single datagridview, you need to convert `Feature`'s rows into columns. Here is complete sample (created with [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/)):

```
void Main()
{
    //create human list     
    List<Human> people = new List<Human>()
    {
        new Human(){Id = "H1", validated =false, features = new List<Feature>()
            {
                new Feature(){feature_id = "H1F1", value ="Feature 1"},
                new Feature(){feature_id = "H1F2", value ="Feature 2"}
            }},
        new Human(){Id = "H2", validated =false, features = new List<Feature>()
            {
                new Feature(){feature_id = "H2F1", value ="Feature 1"},
                new Feature(){feature_id = "H2F2", value ="Feature 2"},
                new Feature(){feature_id = "H2F3", value ="Feature 3"},
                new Feature(){feature_id = "H2F4", value ="Feature 4"},
                new Feature(){feature_id = "H2F5", value ="Feature 5"}
            }}
    };
    //create datatable
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    //add known columns (related to Human)
    dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[]
    {
        new DataColumn("Id", typeof(string)),
        new DataColumn("validated", typeof(string))
    });
    //get max. of futures
    int fc = people.Select(x=>x.features.Count).Max();
    //add columns related to Feature
    for(int i=0; i<fc; i++)
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn($"Feature {i}"));
    //add data to datatable
    foreach(Human h in people)
    {
        //add Human details
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Id"] = h.Id;
        dr["validated"] = h.validated;
        //add Feature details
        for(int i=0; i<h.features.Count; i++)
        {
            Feature f = h.features[i];
            dr[$"Feature {i}"] = f.value;
        }
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
    //datatable is ready to use
    //dump its content ;)
    dt.Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class FeatureBook
{
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
}
public class Feature
{
        public string feature_id { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
}
public class Human
{
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public bool validated { get; set; }
        public List<Feature> features { get; set; }
        public override string ToString() => Id;
}
```

Note: there's few other ways to achieve that, but i wanted to show you the simplest way ;)